# Scala most efficient Map implementation

Tags: performance, scala, dictionary

What is the best bet when a scala Map is created and used in a single thread? (Like the java analogous best bet on StringBuffer compared with StringBuilder for constructing strings).

The kind of constraints to choose the Map are:

- the map is created once with multiple additions/updates on possible already existing keys
- nothing is deleted from map - so this kind of operation might not be needed
- map could have thousands of values (not so big)
- the usage is from the same thread (so there is no concern about accessing/updating the map in parallel)
- the signature of map might be Map[String,T]. In case there is a reason a Map[Int/Long,T] could be used.

I investigated

- collection.immutable.Map (that initially works **optimized** for few keys)
- collection.immutable.HashMap
- collection.mutable.OpenHashMap
- collection.mutable.HashMap

The test showed that there is no clear winner with 50000 keys.
I found some

- [simple microbenchmarks comparing Scala vs Java mutable map performance - 201](https://gist.github.com/pchiusano/1423303) that suggest that OpenHashMap might be a good bet
- [New collections in Scala 2.7.2 - 2008](http://www.drmaciver.com/2008/08/new-collections-in-scala-272/)
- the official [scaladoc Performance Characteristics](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/collections/performance-characteristics.html) doesn't offer orientations except that all Map implementation take **eC - effectively constant time** for lookup and add.

Nevertheless the question is what is the safest bet in general on such circumstances and why?

Comment: Unless you have some reasonably specific workload in mind or you write for some environment with specific constraints (low memory, only one processor) it *sounds* like your research has already turned up the fact that *in the general case* any of the `Map` implementations will work well enough that they won't be a bottleneck.  How would you define "best"; smallest `eC`, least memory for `N` keys, smallest amount of garbage generated for inserts, fewest context switches when performing operations `A -> B -> C`, some combination of the above or something else entirely?

Answer (score 9):

If your map is not extremely tiny and not huge, and your key is a `String`, then `collection.mutable.AnyRefMap` is a good bet.  `collection.mutable.LongMap` is even faster if you can have `Long` keys.  The reason they exist is precisely to be fast for common use cases.

If most maps are incredibly tiny (0-4 elements), then `LinkedHashMap` tends to be best because it avoids the overhead of a hash table.  (Immutable maps are also not bad when 4 or fewer elements.)

If maps are really huge (100s of millions of key/value pairs) then the standard `collection.mutable.HashMap` is the way to go because performance degrades slightly more gracefully as you run out of space for separate keys.